# How to fill up the interior of the circles with red, blue and green colors?

Tags: plotting

```
ContourPlot[{x^2+y^2==1, x^2+y^2==4, x^2+y^2==9},{x,-4,4},{y,-4,4},


ContourStyle->{Red,Blue,Green}]
```

Answer (score 4):

[`ContourShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourShading.html) is the option to shade regions between contours.

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 Contours -> {1, 4, 9}, ContourShading -> {Red, Blue, Green, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: The problem is solved. Could you please edit or remove the plot(for copyright issues)? It would be highly appreciated if you do so. Please.

Comment: @Saha, what does copyright have to do with the plot? Have you already seen [the licensing terms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) for using Stack Exchange?

Comment: Thank you so much for removing it. Actually I am trying to make some notes. this plot may be there with the same legend name. So. If I try to upload in some specific portal they may not allow me to upload it.

Comment: @Saha, then you misunderstand the terms of use of Stack Exchange. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) again. You can always use images from this site **as long as there is attribution/citation**, but no one is obligated to remove their work just because you asked.

Comment: @SahabubJahedi unless I am mistaken, if you make this yourself, for publication, for example, likely you would 1. Improve the appearance of the frame and labels and 2. Be creating your own file, so neither the image previously seen here nor the one in the other answer would be infringed upon.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. @JM I have gone through it and properly understood. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CATrevillian, I will do that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[{x^2+y^2<=9,x^2+y^2<4,x^2+y^2<=1},{x,-4,4},{y,-4,4},PlotStyle->{Red,Blue,Green}]
```

[image]

I also reversed the order of your expressions, so the smaller ones would show on top of larger ones.

Comment: Thank you so much.